# Passing string containing new line characters from VB.NET to C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

I have a VB program that passes a string as input to a C# method. The input could contain escape characters like \n which the C# method would try to split on.

Example VB method:

```
Module VBClass
Sub Main()
    Dim c As CSharpClass = New CSharpClass()
    c.MyMethod("Hello\nWorld\nFrom\nMike")
End Sub
End Module
```

Example C# method:

```
public class CSharpClass
{
    public void MyMethod(string input)
    {
        string[] sSplit = input.Split('\n');
    }
}
```

However, when the C# method receives the string, it's of the form "Hello\\nWorld" which won't split on the delimeter \n.

From the various posts I've Googled, I think VB treats escape sequences as regular parts of the string so then C# throws a double-slash on it to treat it literally.

If my guess is even close to the truth, is there a way to pass the string so that C# can split on \n ?

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions. I've added some test calls to the VB Sub and will go with the third one (replace with vbLf).

```
    c.MyMethod("Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "World")
    c.MyMethod("Hello" + vbLf + "World")
    c.MyMethod("Hello\nWorld\nFrom\nMike".Replace("\n", vbLf))
```

Comment: All your assumptions are incorrect.. How about posting a compilable code showing your problem?

Comment: VB.NET does not consider the \ char as a escape char.  It handles it literally as a \, so you are receiving the correct value on the C# side.

Comment: `CSharpMethod("Hello" & vbLf & "World")`

Comment: You could use [Regex.Unescape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx) if the characters you want to use fall within what it converts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm new to posting on StackOverflow. I figured out what I needed and think I should add a post rather than edit my original response.

I'm going to run a .Replace on my string before I pass it to the C# method. It's received properly and can be split successfully. Thanks to Sehnsucht who suggested vbLf because Environment.Newline wasn't working for me.

```
MyStringInput.Replace("\n", vbLf)
```

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` could have worked but that would have a hidden a subttle bug as it's environment dependent as stated in it's documentation

Comment: Posting this as an answer was the right thing to do, since this post describes how you solved your problem.